# Weblogic server status script using unix batch file

Tags: java, unix, weblogic, weblogic11g

I am checking my weblogic server status(running or stop) through weblogic console. But i paln to automate by using unix script. Can u plz give me the unix scripts(.bat) to check the web logic server stsus. After running unix(.bat) i want to track server status in text file.

Comment: .bat is for Windows. Also please, don't ask the same question 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.wikiconsole.com/wiki/?p=301) example does what you need. With a few minor tweaks, you can get it to work for you.